# Jura Class: Alternative to \lowertitleback

Tags: koma-script, scrjura

The `jura` class is based on KOMA-script so I thought that the `\lowertitleback` command might work, but unfortunately it's not recognized (undefined control sequence). I'm typesetting a legal document and the jura defaults solve a lot of my problems. Unfortunately, the documentation is in German only.

EDIT: The `\lowertitleback` command needs to come before `\maketitle`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{jura}
\title{big book}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\lowertitleback{
here is some text}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
here is more text
\end{document}
```

Comment: `jura`(https://www.ctan.org/pkg/jura) is based on `report` and the version on CTAN is from 1998.

Comment: [`scrjura`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrjura) on the other hand is a package by the author of KOMA script and can be used with `scrreprt` for example.

Comment: @moewe: changing the document class to scrreprt and adding the scrjura package lets the text compile, but for some reason the \lowertitleback doesn't work. Changing the document class to scrbook also compiles, but the \lowertitleback doesn't work. This error is thrown: LaTeX Warning: Command \@doendpe  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

Comment: Obviously `\lowertitleback` makes only sense with document classes that use a two-sided layout, so `scrbook` would be a better choice than `scrreprt` with the default values (but you can use `twoside` with `scrreprt`). You need to issue `\lowertitleback` before `\maketitle`. But changing your class from `jura` to `scr...` will probably also cause a lot of other things to look different, so I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the document class to scrbook causes spacing errors in the table of contents. Is there any way to add the \lowertitleback command to the jura class??

Comment: Probably, but I don't have the time at the moment for digging into KOMA script sources and isolating the definition of `\lowertitleback`, then going back to`jura.cls`  and implanting things there. It might be easy, but it could also be complicated or just very tedious. You may want to look into making the switch to `scrbook` or `scrreprt`. If there are "spacing errors" you could try and resolve them.

Comment: You could also simply do what `lowertitleback` does manually. Just add a new page after `\maketitle` and `\vfill` and write what you want.

Comment: `\maketitle
\newpage
\null\vfill 
here is some text
\newpage`. Or to be more KOMA-y `\maketitle
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
Upper
\end{minipage}\par
\vfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
Lower
\end{minipage}\par
\newpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `jura` is a little bit outdated.  Better you use KOMA-Script with class `scrbook` and called package `scrjura`.

With using `scrbook` (or class `scrreprt` with option `twoside`) command `\lowertitleback` can be used.

So with the following code for a complete `scrjura` document

```
\documentclass[%
  english           % Language
 ,paper=a4          % DIN A4
 ,fontsize=12pt     % 
 ,parskip=half-     %  
 ,numbers=noenddot  % numbers without end dot
]{scrbook}% scrreprt scrartcl

\usepackage{blindtext}      % dummy text

\usepackage[english]{babel} % ngerman

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{enumerate}      % to change numbering sign

\usepackage[%
  juratotoc%=1              % juratotoc=0 0 chapter, 1 section
 ,clausemark=forceboth   % 
 ,juratocnumberwidth=2.5em  % 
 ,ref=long                  % (§ 314 paragraph 2 sentence 2), short numeric
]{scrjura}  
\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{'S}{\Sentence\ignorespaces}% to number first sentence
\defineshorthand{'.}{. \Sentence\ignorespaces}% next sentence numbered

\usepackage{graphicx}       % 

\usepackage[%
% footsepline        % 
 ,headsepline        % 
%,automark           % 
]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % make own header and footer

\pagestyle{scrheadings}         % definition follows
\chead{}                        % empty
\ohead{\claimnumber}            % current claim no
\ihead{Example}                 % fixed text
\cfoot{\pagemark}               % pagenumer in footer

 \usepackage{showframe}          % shows typing area and margins

% line for signature
\newcommand{\dotbox}[2][.5\linewidth]{\hbox to #1 {\dotfill}\noindent#2} 

%\renewcommand*{\thecontractSubClause}{{\theClause~\alph{contractSubClause})}}
%\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\makebox[6em][l]{#1}}% Länge Zahl dreistellig>

\newcommand*{\claimnumber}{Cl~4711}


\begin{document}

\title{big book}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\lowertitleback{here is some text for the lower title back}
\maketitle


\tableofcontents  
\listoffigures

\addsec{Introduction}
\blindtext

%\parnumberfalse\section{ABSCHNITT}\parnumbertrue
\section{Dummy Text}
\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Name, address and year}}
\label{p.name}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit'.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  

\SubClause{title={Sub paragraph}}\label{p.subp}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit'.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit'.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit'.\label{p.name1}  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  

See figure~\ref{fig:ExampleImage}! 

See ref: \ref{p.name1}.

See refL: \refL{p.name1}. 

See refS: \refS{p.name1}. 

See refN: \refN{p.subpdummy}. See \refN{p.name1}. 

See refClause: \refClause{p.name1}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example image}
  \label{fig:ExampleImage}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet,  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\begin{enumerate}[\qquad a)]
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  \item consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{enumerate}

\SubClause{title={Sub paragraph},dummy}\label{p.subpdummy}
\end{contract}


\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\blindtext
\end{contract}

\appendix % 

\section{Dummy Text Appendix}
\blindtext


\clearpage
Signatures:

\vspace{8ex}\dotbox{First Person}

\vspace{4ex}\dotbox{Second Person}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]